# How to show a couple of equations in incremental way in xaringan?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

Hi I was wondering how to show two equations in incremental way using `xaringan` in `rmarkdown` slides like using `\pause` command in `beamer`.

---

1. ax+by = c (equation 1)
2. dx+ey = f (equation 2)

---

Comment: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-format.html#incremental-slides